# Data Abort exceptions on Windows Mobile platform with USB based NIC and ActiveSync

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

i'm working on USB to ethernet device on both WinCE and Windows Mobile 6.5 platforms.

I have connected the USB based NIC to my windows CE craddle which has WinCE 5.0 installed on it.I don't have any problem using this NIC on WinCE5.0.

But when i connected the same NIC in the craddle which has got WIndows Mobile 6.5 installed on it i got this data abort problems!
whenever i try to plg/unplug ActiveSync cable some couple of times to the pc i'm getting the "Data Abort" error frequently.some times the error could be "Prefetch abort" and "Undefined instruction" also!

I could realize that the ActiveSync and the NIC use RNDIS functions.
I saw some of these messages when i debug the problem!

NDIS!ndisMWakeUpDpcX() line 1089 + 8 bytes
NDIS!CeKeDpcQueueThread() line 67 + 24 bytes
COREDLL!ThreadBaseFunc() line 633 + 8 bytes

Can anybody help with you inputs?
Any kind of suggestion is appreciable.

- Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your OEM's NDIS driver (or ethernet driver, or USB driver, etc...) implementation has an issue. You should contact their support line and ask for an update.

-PaulH

Comment: Thanks i got fixed this issue with lil more debugging effort.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised. Can you tell me what the issue ended up being? I'm curious what your code could have done that would cause a DataAbort in NDIS.